# Esc key in Windows Forms application works only with debugger

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Is there any way to handle the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key event in Windows Forms?

Actually it is working fine when I put debugger in the code. Once I remove the debugger it is not getting fired.

What's the problem here?

Comment: The debugger shouldn't make any difference... Could you post your code ?

Comment: private void fullbrowser_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

Answer (score 2):

If it is for a dialog then you can set the property CancelButton (of the form) to the button that cancels (e.g. named btnCancel and with text "Cancel" in a English language application.)

In this case you don't need to handle the key event for the Esc key.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `Form.KeyPreview = true` in your `Form.Designer.cs`. And later you can use Form.KeyPress event.